# Facebook profile link from safari to facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, hyperlink

I am making a personal website with a link to a Facebook profile. If you go to the website from iOS device, I would like the link to open in application, not safari, because a lot of people are not logged-in in safari.

Now this can be done by using "fb://profile/" instead of the link facebook.com/. And I have used following simple code to switch the links:

```
$(function(){
  var iOS = ( navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone)/g) ? true : false );
  if (iOS){
    var href= $(".fb-link").attr("href");
    var res = href.split("/");
    var username = res[res.length - 1];

    $(".fb-link").attr("href", "fb://profile/" + username);
  }
});
```

The only problem is when user does not have the app, then it not only won't open in an app but will fail to open completely.

Is there a way to test if the app is installed? I know when I am programming in the iOS native app I can test if fb:// responds and then I can use the link, but the safari is way more limited. I know it probably won't be possible, just trying if anybody has some experience with this.

Also - is there something similar for android? I don't have much experience with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way in Safari (from a webpage) to determine whether an app is installed or not. The only thing you can try to do is do the fb://profile redirect in javascript, and then set a timeout on your page to see if the redirect succeeded or not. But this is not optimal as there can be error dialogs that pop up.

For Android, you should just go to the www url, and let the Android app handle it via its own intent filter.